# nginx rewrite virtual directory to file

Tags: nginx, virtual-directory

This should be really easy to do but I'm hitting my head on the wall.  If I get a request for www.mysite.com/mypath I want to serve the content of www.mysite.com/myotherpath/thisfile.html.  How can I do this with an nginx config.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use rewrite directive within proper location block. So for example you have basic location which will handle all requests

```
location / {
    /*your rules here*/
}
```

You will need to add another block, which will do for you handling of specific path

```
location /mypath {
    rewrite ^/mypath$ /real/path/to/file/thisfile.html; 
}
```

Also for your server to think in that block that `thisfile.html` is default you can use `try thisfile.html` directive

It is all well explained on official page [Official Nginx RewriteModule page](http://nginx.org/r/rewrite)

Comment: it's a bad way of doing things in nginx, please, see here: http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls

Comment: @VBart I did not find anything related to handling of specific URI on that page.

Answer (score 15):

```
location = /mypath {
    try_files /myotherpath/thisfile.html =404;
}
```

- http://nginx.org/r/try_files
- http://nginx.org/r/location

Comment: This doesn't work if the target is a PHP file.

Comment: How would one make this work for a PHP file?